# Loop Element in salesforce Visual WorkFlow

Tags: visual-workflow, flow, visual-flows

there is a loop element mentioned in Visual Workflow.but in my developer org in which i can create a Flow.when i see palette tab there is no loop element.i can create Apex Classes and Apex Pages with Api Version 30.0.How to create loop element in Flow. please guideline.Thanks :)

there is no sObject Collection in my Flow Resources Tab .here is screenshot of image [image] .Please tell why its not showing sObject Collection ??

Comment: what api version is your org on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the visual flow [loop element](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_elements_loop.htm&language=en_US) is indeed mentioned in the documentation, it is only available as pilot on spring 14 orgs (api 30.0), but will be generally available as part of the summer 14 release (api 31.0).

See the [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_summer14_release_notes.pdf) on page 205.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_resources_sobject_collection.htm) does this help?

In your resources tab do you have sObject collection? This is what you need to use.

Comment: i edited question i uploaded screenshot.No i cant see sObject collection in my resource tab. Please respond :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Winter 18, an exciting new feature has hit the tables, which makes it so easy, to deal with loops while working in visual flows.

After a fast lookup,the record count can be easily fetched in a sobject collection variable and assigned to a number variable. Play around with the number variable directly. 
So finding out the number of open/closed/in progress opportunities gets more easy. Even you dont need to loop through the record set to get the count of records. You already have it before hand.

All you simply need to do is like:

1. Perform a fast lookup with your required filters
   [image]
2. Assign the record count to a sObject collections variable. (in screenshot: nofCases)
3. Use a Assignment step, to assign the variable to a number variable. (Point to note: the assignment variable should be of type number only to make use of equals count operator. In the screenshot, this is called testCount)
   [image]
4. Voila! Now play around with the assigned variable :)